# Why do packages that I am not meant to reference directly show on Nuget?

Tags: nuget

I see the following in Nuget Manage Packages for Solution

[image]

If I am not meant to consume Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI why does it show in Nuget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Browse tab in the NuGet Package Manager shows packages by popularity. It is used to search for a specific package:

**Mircosoft Doc ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio))**

> 2. The Browse tab displays packages by popularity from the currently selected source (see package sources). Search for a specific package using the search box on the upper left....

---

In your case, you are searching for "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", which starts with the same string like "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI" and I guess, it has a high rated popularity.